# What is the significance of the ship in The Lodger?

Tags: doctor-who

The ship that disguises itself as the upstairs flat in Craig's house in *The Lodger* is the same one that River and Rory discover in the tunnels at the end of *The Impossible Astronaut*.

I didn't realise they are the same until my wife pointed it out; I had assumed it belonged to the Silence, but since the upstairs flat ship had crash landed I guess not. Does it crop up anywhere else? Do we know its significance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So far, that ship hasn't cropped up outside of those two episodes (although, I thought the ship only showed up in the second half of that two-parter, which was titled *Day of the Moon*).

It seems unlikely that the ship was constructed by The Silence, as they needed humans to build a simple space suit for them.  We do not yet know where the ship comes from.  Spoilers for *A Good Man Goes To War*.

> However, given the child regenerated at the end of the *Day of the Moon* is likely River, grown up a bit after the events of *A Good Man Goes To War*, and Kovarian wishes to use River as a weapon against the Doctor, it seems possible that Kovarian constructed that ship.  It's an attempt to make a TARDIS, and a weapon against the Doctor could definitely use a way to travel through space and time in a manner similar to the Doctor.

Comment: I agree - and would further note the implications that the right pilot for the ship is not human (it kills humans) and not Time Lord (Dr. said he is "too much for it") but somewhere in-between.  Perhaps you are correct about who constructed it and left it on earth, and the intended "weapon" was also the intended pilot.

Comment: Honestly, I hadn't put all these pieces together until I was writing this answer.  This is a pretty great question.

Comment: I'll be watching *Day of the Moon* tonight, so I'll look out for it... I'm actually up to date with the current season, but watching them again. It's shocking how much detail and information I missed the first time around.

Comment: I think all of us did the first time around - there is too much to notice!

Comment: Of course, that is part of the charm of the current series.

Comment: Note that in The Lodger, the pilot is lying dead on the floor, totally unnoticed. Very much a Silence property.

Comment: It's perhaps also worth noting that the ship in The Lodger could have been chock-full of Silence. How would we know?

Answer (score -1):

It looked very similar to a primitive design model of a Tardis. Possibly the attempt of the Silence of perhaps even time lord. It required a time lord to pilot the ship it also possessed a perception filter to hide in plain view. It could a very early model of a Gallifreyan Tardis. One that was perhaps lost over time or maybe even fell through the time vortex like the dalek did in season 1.

Comment: This seems to be speculation with little to back it up.